# Is there any way to get value from bytecode under JDWP without access to source?

Tags: debugging, android, java

When I debug android app through jdwp using jdb, it seems I can't get anything from the bytecode level. I know normally it's fine as long as we have the source line info and use a decompiler, but the problem is the author intentionally removed the source line information and I can only get bytecode index but not line number. I want to track the values of the local variables but problem is they are removed intentionally, and in this way I can't just print the local variables.

Is there any way that I can query through debugger to get the temp values similar to the debugging in Windows where we can get the values of registers/memory? Below is an example of the method that I runn into, there's no line info, no method signature info)

XXXClass.onMenuItemClick(), line=-1 bci=1

(stack trace)
 [1] XXXClass.onMenuItemClick (null)